# Loosing session between vb.net page_load and Handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I have a problem managing session in one vb.net web application. I'll try to explain the work flow and the problem and I hope someone knows what is possible happening

I have one page user.aspx
In the user.aspx.vb Page_Load function I'm preforming this operation: `Session("userid") = userId` to store the identifier in the session

Later in the javascript `jQuery(document).ready` I'm doing an ajax call to a handler like this

```
$.getJSON('User.ashx', { a: 'getCategories' }
).done(function (json) {
    //process json response
});
```

In the User.ashx.vb I have the next structure

```
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

Sub ProcessRequestBase(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    ProcessRequest(New HttpContextWrapper(context))
End Sub

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContextBase)
    Dim userId As String = CStr(context.Session("userid"))
    'In this point sometins userId is null and sometimes has the value
    'Handle action to build json response


    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache)
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0")
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    context.Response.Write(resp)
```

In the page_load I set a couple of Session variables and in some ajax requests in the Handler I'm using this values.

In my local computer and another computer I've tried with Windows 7 all is working fine but in the server, with Windows XP, sometimes when I receive the session in the Handler the session is empty.

I've checked and the Session ID is the same between all the requests but the Session is completely empty, but if I refresh the page a couple of time sometimes the value is propagated and the handler can retrieve the value and if I continue refreshing the value is still there during two or three times and later is lost again.

I've search for some Session.abandon() or Session.clear() but is not present in the code

The configuration in web.config for session state is:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do do use Response.End() on that page that sets value to session? Or maybe session doesn't created at the moment of that page?

Comment: Not, I'm not using Response.End() in the aspx.vb. should I use it?
And I don't think the session is not created in the Handler, because the call to the handler is preformed in jquery.Ready and I think that the page_load is executed in the server before to send the page to the client.

Comment: In case if session doesn't exist, and you use `Response.End` and it lost, as Session Cookie won't be set. You can also check `Session.SessionID` property on both page and handler. They should be the same

Comment: As I said in the explanation, the `Session.SessionID` is the same in both places (page_load and Handler) for all consecutive requests